# Extract information from external SOFTWARE registry file

Tags: c++, c, registry

I have to extract some information from SOFTWARE registry file. Like the existing in "/windows/system32/config" but totally independent of current OS

Official Microsoft doc suggests some predefined keys (HKLM, HKCU, etc.) but it looks like there is no opportunity to choose external OS-independent files. RegConnectRegistry() is not the way either because I just have a single SOFTWARE file. Any ideas? I know it is possible because Nirsoft package has such functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "SOFTWARE registry file"? The registry structure is more or less the same since Windows 95, so there should not be any issues with different versions of Windows.

Comment: The registry is by definition not platform independent. So can you tell us what you want to do? Do you want to read settings from registry OR an OS independent file? Then create an abstract baseclass (C++) with getters for your settings and make 2 implementations one for registry, one for files. Then inject that interace with getters into the code that needs those settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, by *"independent of current OS"*, I think you do not mean it needs to be *platform*-independent. You just want to open a registry contained in a file that was manually copied from some *other machine's* `"C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE"` file, and use it similarly to how in RegEdit, you could select the HKLM hive and then from the File menu select "Load Hive…" and then select that file you have at hand. In other words, you want to connect not to the live registry on any particular machine, but just to a file.

In that case, I believe the [Offline Registry Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/offline-registry-library-portal) is what you are looking for. Its [`OROpenHive` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/oropenhive) loads the specified file into memory for further use via its [other functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/offline-registry-library-functions).